# 2D jagged array to 1D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, cuda, jagged-arrays

I need to convert dynamic array of dynamic arrays into 1D array for CUDA computation.

Example pseudo code:

```
x[0] = [1, 4, 3, 9]
x[1] = [2, 0]
x[2] = [5, 7, 6]

y = flatten(x)  // Eg.: [1, 4, 3, 9, 2, 0, 5, 7, 6]
get_index(a, b) // Should return index in 1D array
                // that coresponds to element in original 2D array

y[get_index(0, 2)] = 4
y[get_index(1, 0)] = 2
y[get_index(2, 2)] = 7
```

I found that the best way to pass 2D array to CUDA kernel is to flatten it but it works only for matrix (`i=block.x*M+block.y`) but not when each row has different count of columns.

**EDIT:**

I need to access 1D array elements like it was 2D using params, eg.: a & b.

Comment: x is just an array of arrays, implementation can vary... but the count of elements is dynamic

Comment: Out of curiosity what math operation are you doing on x?  You can't do basic matrix math on that thing with different column counts.  If you are processing them as entries then just stack the rows together as y = [x[i], x[i+1], ..., x[n]]

Comment: Well, first dimension refers to group ID, second refers to node ID and value refers to index in another array and its value should be summed. So no matrix computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

1. Create a 2D matrix that is equal in dimension to the largest `x` dimension.  So if `x` is an array of pointers of length N (each to a vector), and the maximum dimension of any individual vector is M, then create C(N,M), and fill each row of C with a vector of `x`.  Then flatten it and transfer it to the device.  This method, while requiring extra storage, will likely yield the fastest access on the device.
2. Create a "compressed" storage format:

   ```
   xh = [1, 4, 3, 9, 2, 0, 5, 7, 6]
   xi = [0, 4, 6]
   ```

   transfer these vectors to the device (they are already flat.)  On the device, access a member i, of vector j, by:

   ```
   myval = xh[xi[j] + i];
   ```

   for this method you may also want to pass a vector of limits:

   ```
   xl = [4, 2, 3]
   ```

   Because of the indirection through `xi[j]` potentially required for each access, this method may result in slower access on the device.

Comment: Yes, I've got the same idea as your approach 2 but I am trying to found if there is a better solution.

Comment: If the `xi` array is small enough to be put in `__constant__` memory, and you can arrange for *uniform access* (briefly, every thread in a warp, on a given cycle, accesses the same `j`th element of `xi`), then the negative performance penalty of the 2nd approach can be largely mitigated.

Comment: This seems to be the best approach and works well, thank you.

Comment: First question, @RobertCrovella I take it that you're saying if a warp happens to get disparate values of `j`, (i.e. a warp straddles `j` values) then the execution becomes more inefficient. How much worse is this? The computed access offsets into `xh` do not necessarily become non-local/incoherent in this case. Second question, on the device I would be taking a block or global index to figure out what work this kernel should do, to compute `i` and `j` out of it. How am I even supposed to compute `i` and `j` from that single index? I cannot fathom how to do it without having to loop.

Comment: I didn't mention first, but I should have, thank you for this answer, it is helping me a lot. So I thought some more, and I think that the use of a loop with the `xi` array as shown should be fine, if I am looping, then only when the warp happens to straddle across different `j` will they desynchronize. I needn't necessarily worry too much about a loop at the beginning of my kernel that could run for up to 50 iterations if my `xi` has length 50, because I should be dispatching it in such a way to ensure every thread will hit the same number of iterations and obtaining the same value of `j`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way to do this with arrays if you do not know how many columns are in each row.  There is an easy way to do this with a vector though as you can use the iterator ranges.  You can do it like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data2d;
std::vector<int> data1d;
data1d.reserve(data2d.size() * data2d[0].size()); // reserve some memory.  this is a guess of what is needed
for (const auto row : data2d)
    data1d.insert(data1d.end(), row.begin(), row.end());
```

Comment: Seems good, any idea how to convert 1D vector into standard array? Beacuse in CUDA I have to copy memory exactly from host to GPU device - simmilar to malloc and memcpy

My idea:

    int *std_arr = new int(data1d.size())
        for(int i = 0; i < data1d.size(); i++) std_arr[i] = data1d.at(i)

But another issue is how to access this 1D like it was 2D, so by using two coordinates?

Comment: vecor has a `data` method that returns the underlaying array.